# The main idea of dialectical materialism

Tags: translation

I want to translate this sentence into Italian:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectical_materialism

The main idea of dialectical materialism lies in the concept of the evolution of the natural world and the emergence of new qualities of being at new stages of evolution.

My attempt:

L'idea principale del materialismo dialettico si trova nel concetto dell'evoluzione del mondo naturale e la comparsa di nuove qualità di essere ai nuovi certi punti della evoluzione.

Is my translation correct?

If it's not , what would a native speaker suggest ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would be glad if native speakers gave their opinion about my translation.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @kerasmus!

Comment: Thank you dear moderator. I am so glad to be a member of this great site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> L'idea principale del materialismo dialettico si trova nel concetto
>   dell'evoluzione del mondo naturale e la comparsa di nuove qualità di
>   essere ai nuovi certi punti della evoluzione.

You go really great up to "nuovi". I'd translate (making some more changes that are mostly a matter of personal taste) as:

L'idea principale del materialismo dialettico **consiste** nel concetto
   **di** evoluzione del mondo naturale e **nell'**emergere di nuove qualità
   dell'essere **nei nuovi stadi dell'evoluzione**.

(You usually use an apostrophe with *della* and *dello* if the next word starts with vowel).

**UPDATE**: I'm not too clear if the original meaning is similar to "lies in *the twin concepts of evolution and appearance of new qualities", or to "lies in the concept of both evolution and appearance". My translation reflects the first interpretation. In the second you would have

L'idea principale del materialismo dialettico **consiste** nel concetto
   **di** evoluzione del mondo naturale e **dell'**emergere di nuove qualità
   dell'essere **nei nuovi stadi dell'evoluzione**.

(i.e., both *di evoluzione* and *di comparsa* depend by *concetto*).

*UPDATE*: for the difference between *di essere* and *dell'essere*, as well as that between *comparsa* and *emergere*, see the comment by Mauro.

Comment: That is, one should write "dell'evoluzione" instead of "della evoluzione", isn't it?

Comment: Yes. The non-apostrophed version is not incorrect, but it does sound archaic. You'll find it in books up to 1700-1800, for example, as well as the old spelling for "degli", which was "delli". Currently you do not apostroph "della" only if it is the last word on a line; the preference for not having a line ending in apostroph being stronger than that of not having two consecutive vowel sounds.

Comment: This translations sounds wrong to me in a key point: _new qualities of being_ means _nuove qualità dell'essere_. This is no small detail, _l'essere_ (with the article and sometimes capitalised) is a philosophical concept: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essere I also see a difference between _emergence_ and _appearance_.
So: _L'idea principale del materialismo dialettico è nel concetto di evoluzione del mondo naturale e dell'emergere di nuove qualità dell'essere in nuovi stadi dell'evoluzione._

Comment: Yes, I totally agree on *dell'essere*. I'm still of two minds about *emergence* - I've rendered it as *comparsa*, but maybe you're right on this too. Editing answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have an issue with the English too. Do you mean:

> The main idea lies in the concept of (the evolution and the emergence)

i.e., there is a unique concept composed by, so to speak, evolution + emergence; or

> The main idea lies in the concept of the evolution and [in] the emergence,

i.e., the idea lies in two different entities, the concept and the emergence (note: not *the concept of emergence*) (and it seems to me that you need a second 'in' in English too, don't you)?

In Italian, you would have:

> l'idea principale si trova nel concetto **dell'** evoluzione del mondo naturale e **dell'** emergere di nuove qualità

and respectively

> l'idea principale si trova **nel** concetto dell' evoluzione del mondo naturale e **nell'** emergere di nuove qualità.

They both sound grammatically correct to me; however, unless there is a reason against, I would use the plural 'concetti', which would make the statements symmetrical, so to speak:

> l'idea principale si trova nei concetti dell'evoluzione del mondo naturale e dell'emergere di nuove qualità.

(in English too?)

Comment: I think the main sentence in English means this :The main idea lies in the concept of the evolution and [in] the emergence, l'idea principale si trova nel concetto dell' evoluzione del mondo naturale e nell' emergere di nuove qualità. But I would suggest waiting for dear Iserni's opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Althoug it seems the quoted sentence is a bit floppy under a syntactic perspective, the best translation I can perform is the following:

> L'idea centrale del *materialismo dialettico* risiede nel concetto evolutivo del mondo naturale e dell'emergere di nuove qualità sostanziali al procedere dell'evoluzione.

Just I precise I'm not a native speaker.

Goodnight and see you in your dreams.

Comment: I'm upvoting the **very** good choices for *risiede* and *qualità sostanziali* (you need to say *nell'emergere*, not *dell'emergere*, though).

Comment: @lserni, thank you. I didn't use 'nell' because 'dell' is joined with 'nel concetto evolutivo' ('nel concetto evolutivo dell'emergere'), however what you suggested makes sense too, although with a change in meaning.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had thought that the meaning was "lies in the concept of ( (the evolution of the natural world) and (the emergence...) )". I may have to revise my own answer. Thanks!